# Why is my for loop index running backwards?

Tags: swift

New to swift. I am creating a solitaire game.

For the last three days I've been stuck on a particularly pernicious bug. Today I figured out that the bug was due to a for-in loop running backwards. When I printed out the index of an array (the "stackedCards" in the code) containing five objects it printed 4,3,2,1,0. I'm guessing it has something to do with the move SKAction that I am running, but then I set up another testing project with similar functionality and code and it printed out the index the way I would have expected 0,1,2,3,4.

Does anybody have any ideas on why this would be happening?

I should mention that it matters where I put the print(index) statement. When it is outside of the completion block, it prints normally, inside of the completion block is where it prints 4,3,2,1,0.

I appreciate any insight anyone could give me. Thanks!

```swift
    func moveCardAnimation(cardToMoveToPosition: CGPoint, columnNumber: Int, undo: Bool) {

            let yMultiplier = checkIfScrunched(columnNumber: columnNumber)
            var zPositionModifier: CGFloat = 50
            var moveAction = SKAction()
            let endCardX = cardToMoveToPosition.x
            let endCardY = cardToMoveToPosition.y

            for index in 0 ..< stackedCards.count {

                moveAction = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: endCardX, y: endCardY - (yMultiplier * CGFloat(index + 1))), duration: 0.3)

                stackedCards[index].zPosition = zPositionModifier
                //print(index) returns 0,1,2,3,4
                stackedCards[index].run(moveAction) {
                        //print(index) returns 4,3,2,1,0
                    if index == self.stackedCards.count - 1 {

                        self.moveCards(toColumn: columnNumber, undo: false)

                    }
                }

                zPositionModifier += 1

            }
        }
```

Comment: Since you have not shown any code related to how `stackedCards` is being populated, no one can really help.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend you read: https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Proper%20Array%20Iteration.md

Comment: Yes, I didn't show that because I thought this question would get quickly large and unwieldy. Just thought since I'm new to programming that this might be a common thing that folks out there would be able to identify. Thanks for the article, checking it out now.

Answer (score -1):

The key to understanding this is that the closure passed to the run method is *not* executed immediately. Instead the blocks are queued up in a FILO queue. So when you run through your for loop, you are pushing the run closures into the queue. Later the closures are popped off and called in last to first order.

Comment: Interesting! It's not always the case that they are in last to first order though. But, you have given me something to research. Not sure why someone game you a -1 for this answer, without explaining why.

Comment: Granted, it might not be a FILO queue, it might be an unordered set.